# Run junit test certain amount of time

Tags: java, testing, junit

I want to test something for a while, say 5 seconds, and then pass the test if nothing wrong has been asserted. Is this possible with  annotations? Can something like `@Test(uptime=5000)` be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Revised answer after question was edited**

Fundamentally it feels like you're testing the wrong thing here - it seems very odd for "nothing happening" to be a sign of success.

If you want to prove that your algorithm can run for a certain amount of time without failing, I would actually extract out a single cycle, then write a test of something like:

```
@Test
public void fineForFiveSeconds() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long end = start + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(5);
    while (System.nanoTime < end()) {
        test.executeOneIteration();
    }
}
```

This way you don't have a separate thread which has to kill the *working* code, etc.

**Original answer**

This answer was written *before* the question indicated that timing out was a sign of success, not failure.

I think you just want the [`timeout`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#timeout%28%29) attribute in the `@Test` annotation:

```
@Test(timeout = 5000)
```

with documentation:

> Optionally specify timeout in milliseconds to cause a test method to fail if it takes longer than that number of milliseconds.

Comment: Just for clarification, this just fails the test, the thread in which the test method is running is still running, until the JVM is stopped of course.

Comment: I haven't explained myself very well. I want to run for a certain amount of time and if nothing happens then pass the test.

Comment: @demil133: That's a *very* strange requirement - the exact opposite of what I'd normally expect. Normally code not completing in time is a sign of *failure*, not success. Do you really want an implementation of `while (true) {}` to be successful?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for the hint. Maybe it's my point of view what's wrong. I'll try different approximation to the test.

Comment: @demil133: I've edited my answer to indicate a possible approach, but it's still odd :)